# Spring boot OAuth2 client with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-security-oauth2

I am practicing spring boot OAuth2. I have and authorization server, resource server, and client server. I managed to secure an endpoint (`/products`).

I want show a list of products using Thymeleaf.

Here is the controller in the resource server:

```java
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getProducts(final Model model) {
        return (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here is the controller in the client server:

```java
@RestController
public class ArticlesController {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @GetMapping(value = "/articles")
    public String[] getArticles(
            @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("articles-client-authorization-code") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        return this.webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8090/articles")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String[].class).block();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/products")
    public List<Product> getProducts(
        @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("articles-client-authorization-code") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {

        return this.webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8090/products")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient)).accept(MediaType.ALL).retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Product.class).collectList().block();

    }
}
```

With the code above I have a list of JSON Products. What is the best way to show this list as a table with Thymeleaf using the webClient?

Comment: Do you want to keep `ArticlesController` as a `RestController` or would it be ok to just make it a `Controller` and use Thymeleaf template as you normally do? Or do you want to serve a JavaScript client app that would fetch the JSON and turn it into HTML on the client/browser side?

Comment: I want keep ArticlesController as a rest controller , thx.